# rails 5 serializing an object along with other attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, ruby-on-rails-5

In a rails 5.2 app, I am having some problems for using a serializer when from a controller I perform some such this:

```
render json: { status: status, result: user, message: msg }
```

In this case, the render outputs all the fields of the `User` active record. However, for the object `user` I have defined a serializer in a way similar to this:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
end
```

And I have tested it successfully by executing an explicit renderization in this way

```
render json: user
```

Where user is, of course, an instance of `User` class. But, I have already mentioned, the serializer is not being invoked in the former situation (`render json: { status: status, result: user, message: msg }`)

Some clue, idea, etc that helps me to guarantee that the serializer is invoked when the render is called through a hash containing the object?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
render json: { status: status, result: UserSerializer.new(user), message: msg }
```

Comment: Thanks! That works and gives me a good clue about how to solve it in the general situation. That is if instead of `user` I use any other `object` having a serializer.

Comment: @lrleon glad it helped :)